# How can I bind an object to a row in a Swing table?

Tags: java, swing

In my application I have some similar threads doing their stuff and I'd like to represent some of their properties in a row of a table (one thread per row). I'd pass a row object to corresponding thread and update them on changing values, but I couldn't find anything like that in API. So what is the right strategy to keep rows updated with actual properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `JTable`, the traditional way to create such a table would be to have a class implement `TableModel` (or extend `AbstractTableModel` or `DefaultTableModel`).  There you would maintain your data, and do so in such a way that it is easy for you to look up a data structure per Thread. You would implement the `getValueAt` method to return the values for your Threads per row.  to When a Thread's properties change, it would then go an update the TableModel.  Then you would need to tell your `JTable` that your data has changed  and have it update from the model.  You would do this by firing a `tableChanged` event.  `AbstractTableModel` and its descendants have  variety of `fireTableChanged`-type methods available.  Make sure you do this firing of events in the EventDispatchThread.  See [topics on currency in Swing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and the [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for info on worker threads interacting with painting GUIs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at binding apis, e.g. the [JGoodies binding api](http://jgoodies.com/).